# Understanding Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-deployment

I am new `AWS`, I am looking to deploy my Django app  with `RDS`, when I googled  found `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`, which helps to manage app easier but does include `auto_scaling`, `load balancer`, my question is I just want to deploy my Django and `RDS` i don't need load balancer and auto_scaling at this `stage` which occurs more charges, so what should i need to do?

Comment: Those are very low charges, even though auto scaling and load balancing charges wont be applicable for you unless your app has considerable server load, data, etc.

Comment: @Laxmikant thanks for your reply, even though it charges I want to remove those features as of now because I have the basic app where the lot needs to be added. your suggestions about this?

Comment: @ N.HariHaraSudhan - Go for Single Instance env http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html?ref_=pe_395030_31184250_9

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to understand that auto_scaling does not add more cost. Even Elastic Bean Stalk does not incur more cost. Yes Elastic Load balancer has extra cost of around 1 USD per month.  If 1 USD extra is fine with you; then I will say go with BeanStalk so that you are sure that you have take care of all best practices.

Deployment wise Beanstalk is very straight forward. If you find it challenging then u can go with 1 instance deployment.

Comment: I was in development stage only so i thought of not using `load balancer` as of now.

Comment: got it.. i will advise u that use best practices right from beginning.. 1 USD per month is ok..

Comment: I also need another info i followed this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) it asks me to create the key-value pair, but now I want to connect filezilla instance with ec2 where it requires `pem` so how can I get the generated key-value?

Comment: keypair is nothing but pem file

Comment: Amazon Elastic Beanstalk introduces now support for shared load balancers
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-introduces-support-shared-load-balancers/